# Merged questions prevent deletion

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, exact-duplicates, deletion

Trying to cast a delete vote on 
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/204765/show-the-negative-derivative-of-a-function I receive the message<sup>[1]</sup>

> [image: duplicate]

When I [view linked questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/204765?lq=1), I find there is just one<sup>[2]</sup> question. But I can't vote to delete it either, since it was *merged* into the above one, and therefore locked.

---

[1]: This is a feature that [SE introduced](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239597/259867) about a week ago.

[2]: The sidebar says "2 linked questions", due to another bug that [I reported last year](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240538/).

Comment: Fascinating. For what it's worth, I (with mod superpowers) can delete the question that was merged into this question. So I cannot verify your bug. But it sounds annoying.

Comment: If you try (for science) to delete the merge *target*, do you get the same pop-up message I got?

Comment: Yes, I do. I did not delete the other, and then try to delete the target. I have a fear of deleting things, even for science.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only moderators can merge questions. They're expected to perform a thorough review, cleaning up both questions before or after the merge, and not wasting their time on questions that should just be deleted.

But of course, they do make mistakes now and then. If you find a merged question that should be deleted, flag it & bring it to the mods' attention. They can remove both the stub and the question if need-be. I did this for your example by way of demonstration - behold its awe-inspiring deletedness!

If desired, moderators can avoid this situation by just deleting the stub up-front.